# .where returns nil when querying nil attributes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to find an object (Variant) by its attributes using .where, the query works if none of the parameters are nil, otherwise it returns nothing. Here is my code:

```
product.product_options.blank? ? options = [nil] : options = product.product_options
product.product_sides.blank? ? sides = [nil] : sides = product.product_sides
product.product_sizes.blank? ? sizes = [nil] : sizes = product.product_sizes

valid_variants = []

sides.product(sizes, options).each do |side, size, option|
    side.blank? ? side_id = nil : side_id = side.id
    size.blank? ? size_id = nil : size_id = size.id
    option.blank? ? option_id = nil : option_id = option.id

    valid_variants << product.variants.where(product_size_id: size_id, product_side_id: side_id, product_option_id: option_id).first
end
```

In this case product.variants does contain variants that match the side, size and option ids but valid_variants is empty.

Here is the contents of product.variants:

```
{"id"=>1, "product_side_id"=>nil, "product_size_id"=>1, "product_id"=>1, "created_at"=>Mon, 27 Jan 2014 16:28:46 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Mon, 27 Jan 2014 16:28:46 UTC +00:00, "product_option_id"=>1}
{"id"=>2, "product_side_id"=>nil, "product_size_id"=>1, "product_id"=>1, "created_at"=>Mon, 27 Jan 2014 16:28:46 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Mon, 27 Jan 2014 16:28:46 UTC +00:00, "product_option_id"=>2}
{"id"=>3, "product_side_id"=>nil, "product_size_id"=>2, "product_id"=>1, "created_at"=>Mon, 27 Jan 2014 16:28:46 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Mon, 27 Jan 2014 16:28:46 UTC +00:00, "product_option_id"=>1}
{"id"=>4, "product_side_id"=>nil, "product_size_id"=>2, "product_id"=>1, "created_at"=>Mon, 27 Jan 2014 16:28:46 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Mon, 27 Jan 2014 16:28:46 UTC +00:00, "product_option_id"=>2}
```

Here is the contents of valid_variants when using product.variants.where(product_size_id: size_id, product_side_id: side_id, product_option_id: option_id).first

```
[nil, nil]
```

Here is the contents of valid_variants when using product.variants.where(product_size_id: size_id, product_side_id: side_id, product_option_id: option_id)

```
[#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>]
```

Comment: did you check the resulting sql query?? to see if it matches what you want??

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting the `valid_variants` array on each iteration. Move `valid_variants = []` outside of the loop:

```
valid_variants = []
sides.product(sizes, options).each do |side, size, option|
    side_id = side.blank? ? nil : side.id
    size_id = size.blank? ? nil : size.id
    option_id = option.blank? ? nil : option.id

    valid_variants << product.variants.where(product_size_id: size_id, product_side_id: side_id, product_option_id: option_id).first
end
```

Updated your `side_id`, `size_id`, and `option_id` initialization.

Comment: I have moved that out of the each block and it still returns nothing.